# use read_sas to read specific file under a zipped file in R

Tags: r

I have a zipped sas file and there are couple sas files inside that. Just want to know if there is a chance that I can use read_sas function to read specific file under that zipped file? Couldn't find anything online about that.

Checked the ?read_sas nothing mentioned about that.

code I used :

```
# zipped file name: example.zip
# files inside example.zip file are file1.sas7bdat, file2.sas7bdat and targetfilename.sas7bdat
file <- read_sas(example.zip, 'targetfilename.sas7bdat')
```

outcome: read_sas only read the first file inside that zipped file.

Sorted solution:

```
 read_sas(unz("examp;e.zip", "'targetfilename.sas7bdat'"))
```

Comment: Have you tried `read_sas("file2.sas7bdat.zip")` ?

Comment: Just tried, got error ''file2.sas7bdat.zip does not exist" @EmilyKothe

Comment: You'll have to unzip the files first. `read_sas` doesn't understand compressed files with multiple files inside

Comment: @MrFlick, yep. Thanks for that. I have sorted it by this: 
read_sas(unz("examp;e.zip", "'targetfilename.sas7bdat'"))

Comment: you can answer your own question if you've solved the issue yourself.

Answer (score 1):

solved:

```
   read_sas(unz("examp;e.zip", "'targetfilename.sas7bdat'"))
```